# Increase rowspan of a widget by one, Everytime a function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

Is there any way to increase the rowspan of a widget by one every time a function is called. If I configure the `grid` of the widget it just increases it once.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

my_entry = tk.Entry(root)
my_entry.grid(column=0, row=0)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: test(my_entry))
b.grid(column=1, row=0)

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Test")
lbl.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text="Test2")
lbl2.grid(column=1, row=2)


def test(e):
    e.grid_forget()
    e.grid_configure(column=0, row=0, rowspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

But I want to do it every time a function is called.

Comment: As it stands, you are using a constant, `rowspan=2`, value. Use a variable `rowspan=current_rowspan` and increment on every function call.

Comment: You can get the value of `rowspan` using `grid_info()`: `rowspan = e.grid_info()['rowspan']`, then `e.grid_configure(..., rowspan=rowspan+1)`.